# Ways to overcome the 230s hard coded limit to the SCM endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, kudu

**Background**
We have a PHP App Service and MySQL that is deployed using an Azure Devops Pipeline (YML). The content itself is a PHP site that it packaged up into a single file using Akeeba by an external supplier. The package is a Zip file (which can be deployed as a standard Zip deployment) and inside the Zip file is a huge JPA file. The JPA is essentially the whole web site plus database tables, settings, file renames and a ton of other stuff all rolled into one JPA file. Akeeba essentially unzips the files, copies them to the right places, does all the DB stuff and so on. To kick the process off, we can simply connect to a specific URL (web site + path) and run the PHP which does all the clever unpackaging via a web GUI. But, we want to include this stage in the pipeline instead so that the process is fully automated end to end. Akeeba has a CLI as an alternative to the Web GUI deployment, so it should go like this:

1. Create web app
2. Deploy the web site ZIP (zipDeploy)
3. Use the REST API to access Kudu and run the relevant command (php install.php web.jpa) to unpack the jpa and do the MySQL stuff - this normally takes well over 30 minutes (it is a big site and it has a lot of "stuff" to do - but, it does actually work in the end).

The problem is that the SCM REST API has a hard-coded 230s limit as described here: https://blog.headforcloud.com/2016/11/15/azure-app-service-hard-timeout-limit/

So, the unpack stage keeps throwing "Invoke-RestMethod : 500 - The request timed out" exactly on the 230s mark.

We have tried SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT and WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT but, unsurprisingly, they did not make any difference.

```
$cmd=@{"command"="php .\site\wwwroot\install.php .\site\wwwroot\web.jpa .\site\wwwroot"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $creds"} -Body (ConvertTo-Json($cmd)) -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -TimeoutSec 7200
```

I can think of a few hypothetical ways around it (some quite eccentric):

1. Find another way to run CLI commands inside the Web App after deployment other than the Kudu REST API. Is there such a thing? I Googled and checked SO but all I found were pointers to the way we do it (or try to do it) now.
2. Use something like Selenium to click the GUI buttons instead of using the CLI. (I do not know if they would suffer a timeout.)
3. Instead of running the command via Kudu REST, use the same API to create and deploy a script to the web server, start it and then let the REST API exit whilst the script still runs on the Web App. Essentially, bodge an async call but without the callback and then have the pipeline check in  on the site at, say, 5 minute intervals. Clunky.
4. Extend the 230s limit - but I do not think that Microsoft make this possible.
5. Make the web site as fast as possible during the deployment in the hope of getting it under the 4-minute mark and then down-scale it. Yuk!
6. See what the Akeeba JPA unpacking actually does, unpack it pre-deployment and do what the unpackage process does but controlled via the Pipeline. This is potentially a lot of work and would lose the support of the supplier.
7. Give up on an automated deployment. That would rather defeat much of the purpose of a Devops pipeline.
8. Try AWS + terraform instead. That's not a approved infrastructure environment, however.

Given that Microsoft understandably do not want long-running API calls hanging around, I understand why the limit exists. However, I would expect therefore there to be a mechanism to interact with an App Service file system via a CLI in another way. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. As per the OP, unfortunately, we have no control over the code (produced and maintained by a third party) so I think that rules out your 1 and 2. I do not know how to do 3 without code access. Re 4, yes that is an option, though we prefer App Sevices so we don't have to maintain infrastructure. Behind the scenes, we filtered my original options down to: (2) Selenium + Web GUI, (7) Manual and (8) AWS. I now add to this you (9) TCP keepalive and (10) Use a VM. Do you know how to do the TCP keeplive without code access? (E.g. just using the REST API?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4 minute idle timeout on the TCP level and this is implemented on the Azure hardware load balancer. This timeout is not configurable and this cannot be changed. One thing I want to mention is that this is idle timeout at the TCP level which means that if the connection is idle only and no data transfer happening, only then this timeout is hit. To provide more info, this will hit if the web application got the request and kept processing the request for > 4minutes without sending any data back.

Resolution

Ideally in a web application, it is not good to keep the underlying HTTP request open and 4 minutes is a decent amount of time. If you have a requirement about background processing within your web application, then the recommended solution is to use Azure WebJobs and have the Azure Webapp interact with the Azure Webjob to notify once the background processing is done (there are many ways that Azure provides like queues triggers etc. and you can choose the method that suits you the best). Azure Webjobs are designed for background processing and you can do as much background processing as you want within them. I am sharing a few articles that talk about webjobs in detail
· http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx
· https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/

============================================================================

It totally depends on the app.  Message Queue comes to mind.  There are a lot of potential solutions and it will be up to you to decide.

============================================================================

Option #1)
You can change the code to send some sort of header to continue to the client to keep the session open.
A sample is shown here
This shows the HTTP Headers with the Expect 100-continue header:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287673%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
This shows how to add a Header to the collection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287502(v=vs.71).aspx

Option #2) Progress bar

- This sample shows how to use  a progress bar:
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d84f4c89-ebbf-44d3-bc4e-43525ae1df45/how-to-increase-progressbar-when-i-running-havey-query-in-sql-server-or-oracle-?forum=csharpgeneral

Option #3) A common practice to keep the connection active for a longer period is to use TCP Keep-alive. Packets are sent when no activity is detected on the connection. By keeping on-going network activity, the idle timeout value is never hit and the connection is maintained for a long period

Option #4) You can also try the option of hosting your application as an IaaS VM  instead of a APP SERVICE. This may avoid the ARR timeout issue because its architecture is different and I believe that the time-out is configurable.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. In the end, we gave up on the whole solution (Akeeba --> PHP --> App Service) and went for a SaaS solution. However, I'll mark it as answered as, for others facing the same issue, there are some good solutions in there.